# removing disabled attribute from input with onclick or mouseover event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input which ask user to enter text but also the user can use the suggestion from a dropdown select list. when the user selects something from the dropdown the input value changes whatever the user selects on dropdown list. also the input will be disabled when the user selects from the dropdown list. but the user should be able to type again into input box when the user clicks on it.

I have made something it works but it works on first call if you select again it does not work.

I use twitter bootstrap and also selectpicker plugin.

codes

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

                $('.selectlink').selectpicker();
                $(".selectlink").click( function(event) {
                    var selected = $(".selectlink :selected").text();
                    $('.selectgrouplink').val(selected);
                    $('.selectgrouplink').attr('disabled', true);
                });
                $(".disabled-link > div").click( function(event) {
                    $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();
                });
            });
</script>
```

html

```
         <div class="input-append">
            <div class="disabled-link">
              <input name="group" type="text" placeholder="Grup secin" id="appendedDropdownButton" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" class="selectgrouplink" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Lutfen bir grup secin')">
              <div style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;"></div>
            </div>
              <select name="selectlink" class="selectlink">
                <option value="haberler">Popüler Gruplar</option>
                <option value="video">Video</option>
                <option value="komik">Komik</option>
                <option value="fotograf">Fotograf</option>
              </select>
          </div>
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you using `.attr('disabled', true)` and `.prop('disabled', true)` in another?

Comment: Prop is not true is false.

Comment: That was a typo on my part. But the question still stands.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `:disabled`instead

```
$(this).hide().prev("input:disabled").prop("disabled", false).focus();
```